# What does the "Show Images" do for Wordpress music playlist?

Tags: visual-editor, audio, backbone

In the new audio playlist in Wordpress 3.9, you can check the options:

- Show Tracklist
- Show Artist Name in Tracklist
- Show Images

The last option doesn't really make sense. There is no option to set an image for an audio track - unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's for the album cover in the playlist. WordPress automatically tries to search for it based on ID3 tags in the media file that you upload. "Show Images" is for disabling the artwork (if it's found).

So far, there's no way to set it manually, as far as I can tell.